# Electric Dryer Issue: Clothes Damp in Sensor Drying Mode

Tags: dryer

I have an older Whirlpool, model LER5848EQ4 electric dryer.  My clothes are now coming out a bit damp when using the sensor-based drying cycle, even when set to the maximum "Heavy" dryness level.  I have taken off the back and thoroughly cleaned the lint filter and duct, vent hose, and all the various channels.  I also replaced both the dryer cycling thermostat and the sensor electrodes.  But none of this helped.  I was thinking of next replacing the heating element. But I was thinking that if using sensor-based drying, the dryer should still keep running until the clothes are dry, regardless of how inefficient the heating element might have become over time.  What should I try next?

Comment: FWIW, electric heating elements don't normally "become inefficient"; their efficiency in converting electricity to heat is always 100%. They may fail open (and stop producing heat) or they may fail short (and most likely trip a fuse or a thermal cutoff sensor, or in the worst case catch fire), but they don't slowly degrade.

Comment: That suggests lint, dust or some such is clogging the sensors.

Answer (score 7):

Replace the drier, or learn how long it normally takes to get things actually dry, and use the timer, not the sensor that doesn't work even after you replaced its electrodes. One of these options costs much less. *Or* learn how much *additional* time they need after the sensor gets them to "a bit damp."

Throwing parts at it is expensive; a broken heating element would be obvious, in that clothes would not dry or even get warm, so that can be ruled out if they do become dry after adequate time and are above room temperature.

Comment: @BillyOregon edit the question where it is visible ... don't be putting the correction into a comment at an answer

Comment: Moisture sensor kit (p/n 279366) is <$50 on Amazon.  OP can decide if it's worth throwing parts at the problem, or he could try the method suggested here: https://www.appliancepartspros.com/answers-for-whirlpool-sensor-279366-ap3094143-question-252085.html

Comment: @Huesmann I assume that's already been done: "*I also replaced both the dryer cycling thermostat and the sensor electrodes.*" And it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: A part site suggested trying to replace the moisture sensor control board since I've already replaced the thermostat and sensor electrodes.  This board is  super easy to get to and used boards cost just $10. So, I will give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 6):

Run smaller dryer loads. I run into the same issue if I overload. In the other hand, getting stuff onto hangers still slightly damp lets wrinkles "hang out" so I tend to just not worry about it

Comment: We are already using pretty small loads.  But thanks for the tip.